# Javascript regex grouping

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that would easily replace an input name such as "holes[0][shots][0][unit]" to "holes[0][shots][1](http://jsfiddle.net/PH2Rh/)[unit]". I'm basically cloning a HTML input and would like to make sure its position is incremented.

I got my regex built and working correctly using this (awesome) tool : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Here is my current regex :

```
(.*\[shots\]\[)([0-9]+)(\].*\])
```

and I am using a replace such as :

```
$12$3
```

this transforms "holes[0][shots][0][unit]" into "holes[0][shots][2][unit]". This is exactly want I want. However, when I try this in javascript (http://jsfiddle.net/PH2Rh/) :

```
var str = "holes[0][shots][0][units]";
var reg =new RegExp("(.*\[shots\]\[)([0-9]+)(\].*\])", "g");

console.log(str.replace(​reg,'$1'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I get the following output : holes[0

I don't understand how my first group is supposed to represent "holes[0", since I included the whole [shots][ part in it.

I appreciate any inputs on this. THank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In strings, a single `\` is not interpreted as a Regex-escaping character. To escape the bracket within string literals, you have to use two backslashes, `\\`:

```
var reg = new RegExp("(.*\\[shots\\]\\[)([0-9]+)(\\].*\\])", "g");
```

A preferable solution is to use RegEx literals:

```
var reg = /(.*\[shots\]\[)([0-9]+)(\].*\])/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, this works:

```
var str = "holes[0][shots][0][units]";
var reg = /(.*\[shots\]\[)([0-9]+)(\].*\])/;
console.log(str.replace(​reg,'$1'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```